# Cannot align ticks to bars in bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying out d3 ,started out with trying to create a bar chart.

This is what 've managed to do :
[image]

Notice how the ticks are not perfectly aligned with the bars  ,[image]

ideally I want to have them right under the bars ,centering them under each bar.

But I can't seem to control their location. Here is how I am adding them

```
  //label array is an array of letter,correposding to a value in the original css file
 var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(labelArray)
      .range([0, width])
      .rangeBands([0, width], 0.3);



 var hGuide=d3.select('svg').append('g') ;
      hAxis(hGuide);
      hGuide.attr('transform','translate('+margin.left+','+(height+margin.top)+')');
```

And this is how I position the bars

```
canvas

  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left +', '+ margin.top +')')
  .selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
  .enter().append('rect')
      .style('fill', function(d,i) {
          return colors(i);
      })
      .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
      .attr('x', function(d,i) {
          return (i*(width/labelArray.length));
      })
      .attr('height', 0)
      .attr('y', height)
```

Don't seem to get my head around this ,

Here is the complete code on fiddle, the cross origin policy would mostly stop you from running the code.Although I thought it was helpful to describe it like this :https://jsfiddle.net/vhs1fwfp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the rectangles like this for the bar chart make use of the xScale instead doing like below.

```
selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
        .enter().append('rect')
            .style('fill', function(d,i) {
                return colors(i);
            })
            .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr('x', function(d,i) {//this is wrong
                return (i*(width/labelArray.length));//remember variable i will be 0 @ the start of the loop that is why first bar starts with 0.
            })
            .attr('height', 0)
            .attr('y', height)
```

So instead of doing this:

```
.attr('x', function(d,i) {
                return (i*(width/labelArray.length));
            })
```

do this:

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) { return xScale(labelArray[i]); })
```